# Hide JWT token in Javascript

Tags: javascript, authorization, jwt

I've implemented a JWT authentication for my rest api.

I'm struggling to understand how to hide the token in JavaScript.

For example, all the clients (web browser and mobile phone app) will call my api with an header:

```
Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOXXXXXXX
```

In PHP it makes sense, but in JavaScript "everyone" can see the token. So what's the point of having one?

Even if the token expires after X minutes, all you need to do is get the new token every X minutes, and you have access to the same API.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Why are you trying to hide your token? The purpose of a token is so you don't have to use your credentials - which do need to be kept secret

Comment: `how to hide the token` - you don't understand JWT tokens in that case. There is no reason to hide it

Comment: So another application cannot connect directy to my api without using my website. Right now they can easily : read the token from my website, use my api directly, refresh the token when needed.

Comment: The token is generated on the server when the user logs in, then sent back to and stored locally on the client, and sent along on every subsequent request. See this: https://cdn.auth0.com/content/jwt/jwt-diagram.png

Comment: In my case there is no login/password for the end users. The website is public and every one can access the page. The token is generated by the server to get access to the api.

Comment: That's pretty important information though, don't you think? Anyway, you can always route your API requests through your PHP server.

Comment: Do not use the same token for website and API, or include an audience claim `aud:website` and reject these tokens in the API

Comment: @pedrofb Ok I guess this is the best approach. A different authorization token with a very short expiry for the javascript side. Thank you all for your help and sorry if I was not clear in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I have understand of Token, they are used to help the server to know 'who is sedding this request' and if this person has the right to.

they are made for simplification of this process, not for security.

If you don't use Token, I think, that means you have to send and check password at each request.

But yes, the information inside **is not hidden**, as you read [Here](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> **Do not put secret information in the payload or header elements of a JWT unless it is encrypted**

I know that you can encrypt your token, but I've never done this, so I can't say much about it.

A solution is using **SSL/HTTPS** for security.